# What is Limitation of Visual web developer 2010?

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET with C# Free or not?

Visual web developer Free or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is free. Get it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express

And the relevant licensing information:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/Support-faq.aspx

> Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?
>
> Yes, there are no licensing restrictions for applications built using Visual Studio Express Editions.

Note that this is for Visual Studio 2008. I couldn't find the 2010 version of this right away, but I doubt it's changed.  Also be careful not to use the "Terms of Use" link at the bottom of the download page.  That has language that contradicts this, but it's just legalese that applies to the web site itself.  Visual Web Developer will be covered by it's own license.

Also note that you will have to give Microsoft your e-mail address to get a Windows Live ID to access the site where you register for a license key, and you'll also want a Microsoft Windows server for your hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 Express is Free.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

You can choose to develop in Visual Basic or C#.